# How do I set some global variables in Magento

Tags: php, magento, variables

For my webshop (in Magento) I need a few variables I declare in the top of the website to echo on other pages/static blocks.

For example I need the time to show trough a static block on this page:

"top.phtml"

```
{{block type="core/template" template="customphp/top.phtml"}}
```

But for some reason it doesn't show up on a php echo in other pages.
The reason I don't declare the variable on the page itself is because I need it on many more places.

Is there a way to do this without doing things in the core?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for the Magento Registry http://prattski.com/2014/09/23/using-the-magento-registry-mageregister/

Answer (score 0):

```
System -> Custom Variables
```

Using this menu path you can add your global variable and that is use anywhere in magento.